# Gnuplot: Split data file into set number of rows and plot each set separately

Tags: gnuplot

Greeting everyone, I have a data file containing n*16 rows. I need to split it into n sets of 16 rows, i.e from 1 to 16, 17 to 32 and 32 to 48 etc. The output will produce n files with 16 rows of data each.  The sample code is given below.

````
set terminal png
set output 'Test1.png'
set xr [0.0:8.0]
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 1 pt 11   
#        MULTIPLE GRAPH for type 1 or type 2 solutions
plot  'test1.dat' u 3:8 every ::0::16  with  lines ls 1 title "Number Density"
EOF  ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
### plot blocks à 16 rows into 16 files
reset session
set terminal png

FILE = 'Test1.dat'

myFile(n) = sprintf("Test%02d-%02d.png",(n-1)*16+1,n*16)

do for [i=1:16] {
    set output myFile(i)
    plot FILE u 3:8 every ::(i-1)*16::i*16-1 w l
}
set output
### end of code
```

Comment: @SofaScientist glad to hear, then please check the check mark at the answer indicating that the question is answered.